# Schedule some jobs with php/python at some specific time without crontab

Tags: php, python, schedule, at-job

I have some irregular jobs to do(frequent and many), so I can't use the crontab.

for example:

- send an email at 10:20AM on July 22 2012
- post a article at 11PM tonight
- run a script at 9:50AM tomorrow.

I found the linux commond `at`, but that can't be managed easily, otherwise, I search some message queue (like zeromq) and gearman, they can't do scheduled jobs or delayed jobs too.

Are there other solutions?

Comment: Did you try online cron services?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about [APScheduler](http://packages.python.org/APScheduler/)?

```
import time
from datetime import datetime
from apscheduler.scheduler import Scheduler

# Schedule my_job for year, month, day, hour (out of 24), minute.  Then wait.
sched = Scheduler()
sched.start()
def my_job(text):  print text
job = sched.add_date_job(my_job, datetime(2011, 7, 11, 22, 04), ['hello'])
while True:
  print datetime.now()
  time.sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, your choice is cron or manually manage sleep.

If you're using Django, however, this has [already been accomplished for you](http://code.google.com/p/django-cron/).